# Colour fill based on values?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for a way in Python/matplotlib/pandas to create a color fill for a graph similar to this (Source: http://www.scminc.com/resources/SCM_TIPSTRICKS_Petrel_Well_Sections_2013_July14.pdf):

[image]

It uses a color map for the fill (left of the image), and based on a specific interval on the x-axis assigns a color to it. Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution, and since I am pretty new to Python in general, I am unable to find a way to do that.

Many thanks

Comment: well, if you don't absolutely have to have a range of colours you could use [fill_between](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html). Otherwise you might need something like a [patch collection](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/patch_collection.html).  You might also consider making a rectangular image and [clipping it](http://matplotlib.org/examples/images_contours_and_fields/image_demo_clip_path.html) with a patch.

Comment: ..continuing previous comment... for the final option, you would need to use a [Polygon patch](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Polygon).

Comment: `pcolor` might also work for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plot the fill as a background with `imshow`, then clip it. You can use `fill_betweenx` to make the mask.

Here's an example using random data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

# Make a random x and a y to go with it.
np.random.seed(26)
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 200).cumsum()
y = np.arange(x.size)

# Set up the figure.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 10))

# Make the background 'image'.
im = ax.imshow(x.reshape(-1, 1),
               aspect='auto',
               origin='lower',
               extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()]
              )

# Draw the path.
paths = ax.fill_betweenx(y, x, x.min(),
                         facecolor='none',
                         lw=2,
                         edgecolor='b',
                        )

# Make the 'fill' mask and clip the background image with it.
patch = PathPatch(paths._paths[0], visible=False)
ax.add_artist(patch)
im.set_clip_path(patch)

# Finish up.
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

This yields:

[image: some random data filled with colour]

Comment: This answer assumes regular sampling. We (@kwinkunks etc) had a chat on Twitter:
https://twitter.com/JesperDramsch/status/1174347214401019904

Can be solved by resampling:

new_y = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), len(y)); 
new_x = np.interp(new_y, y, x)

Comment: Here's another completely different approach: https://github.com/jessepisel/5minutesofpython/blob/master/Well%20log%20plots/gamma%20ray%20colors.ipynb