# X-min and X-max from fill_between in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, fill, between

is there a way to get the x-max and x-min coordinates from resulting interpolated region after doing `fill_between()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes.**

The `fill_between()` function returns a [`matplotlib.collections.PolyCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html), which has an attribute called `_paths`. This contains the paths present in the plot, with data-space coordinates. For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> 
>>> x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 16)
>>> y = np.sin(x)
>>> 
>>> polys = plt.fill_between(x, y, where=(y > 0))
>>> 
>>> polys._paths
[Path(array([[0.6981317 , 0.        ],
    [0.6981317 , 0.64278761],
    [1.3962634 , 0.98480775],
    [2.0943951 , 0.8660254 ],
    [2.7925268 , 0.34202014],
    [2.7925268 , 0.        ],
    [2.7925268 , 0.        ],
    [2.0943951 , 0.        ],
    [1.3962634 , 0.        ],
    [0.6981317 , 0.        ],
    [0.6981317 , 0.        ]]), array([ 1,  2,  2, 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2, 79], dtype=uint8))]
```

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36954416/colour-fill-based-on-values/48951904#48951904) of using this path to clip an image plot.